# Do something when workbook gets closed

Tags: vba, excel

How can I do this in VBA?

```
    if (thisWorkbook.close=true) then 
           'do something (send email)
           'and then close the workbook
    end if
```

Before closing my file, I want to send an email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765%28v=office.15%29.aspx). In the `ThisWorkbook` module, add this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'do something (send email)
End Sub
```

You can even have this code inserted automatically like this:

[image]

and then this:

[image]

In that listbox you will see [all the other available Workbook events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301171%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: Couldn't have been answered better +1

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: I have an error: Compile error: Ambiguous name detected: Workbook_BeforeClose.